# presentModalViewController:Animated is deprecated in ios6

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

I am using the following code for an image picker. But when I run it in the simulator, I have a memory leak and I get a warning about `presentModalViewcontroller:animated` being deprecated in iOS6. I also get `dismissModalViewController:animated` deprecated. I'm using the SDK 6.1.

Code for ImagePicker:

```
- (void)showAlbum:(id)sender { 
    imagePicker=[[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    imagePicker.allowsEditing =NO;
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
}

- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker{
    //release picker
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 218, accepted):

Use this line & check:

```
[self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: In place of this:[self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];

Comment: and for dismiss use this:[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: Getting same memory leak problem and app will close

Comment: Where you getting problem means in which line?

Comment: Im getting this error 'UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation', reason: 'preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation must return a supported interface orientation!'

Comment: Look this link & follow:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12690963/preferredinterfaceorientationforpresentation-must-return-a-supported-interface-o

Comment: this isn't the modal view controller behavior. A modal view controller should block the calling thread. The calling thread should wait for the modal dialog to close. But this doesn't block

Answer (score 17):

```
[[Picker presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Instead of

```
 [[Picker parentViewControl] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

and

```
[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Instead of

```
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```

Comment: so now we have presentViewController and do not specify that the view controller should be modal?

Answer (score 5):

As Vishal mentioned

> ```
> [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
> [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
> ```

make sure you have added "completion:nil" as well

Answer (score 4):

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(presentViewController:animated:completion:)])
{
    [self presentViewController:objSignupViewController animated:^{} completion:nil];
}
else
{
    [self presentModalViewController:objSignupViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
[self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

And then for your dismissal modal use:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:controller completion:nil];
```

or

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```