# How to Use core plot sliceWasSelectedAtRecordIndex so that clicking on a pie chart a tableview is called?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-plot

Is there a way to call a tableview after clicking on a coreplot pie chart ? I'm thinking about the method pieChart:sliceWasSelectedAtRecordIndex: but how can i create a segue without xcode ? Sorry for the newbie question but I always use Xcode for segue and in this case my piechart is created via code so there is nothing i can drag between views.

Thanks, dom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can normally call `performSegueWithIdentifier:` in your view controller's code, but this relies on having a segue already set up in the storyboard to reference. If you do have your segue setup then you can push the new View controller like so:

```
- (void)pushMyNewViewController
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"myidentifier" sender: self];
}
```

So you can create a method that programmatically push a new Viewcontroller like so without using the interface builder. :)

```
- (void)pushMyNewViewController
{
    MyNewViewController *myNewVC = [[MyNewViewController alloc] init];

    // do any setup you need for myNewVC

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:myNewVC animated:YES];
}
```

And then in your `pieChart:sliceWasSelectedAtRecordIndex:` method you can call your newly created method like so:

```
[self pushMyNewViewController];
```

Comment: No problem dude. Nice one

Comment: It does what i need, indeed !! Xcode however tells me that presentModalViewController is deprecated since iOS6. At this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15874094/presentmodalviewcontrolleranimated-is-deprecated-in-ios6)  I found the workaround, which is to use:  presentViewController:animated:completion: instead, so now no more warning. Thanks again, dom.

Comment: Ah ok, you're using iOS7. Thats fine dude, presentingViewController is definitely what you need to be using or pushViewController! Anyway, ive updated the code. Have a good one

Comment: Actually embedding  my view into a Navigation controller is a great idea (was missing the "back" button with presentingViewController...) . Cheers & Thanks!