# App getting crash while presenting UIImagePickerController in iOS6

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimagepickercontroller, uiinterfaceorientation

I am presenting `UIImagePickerController` from the view controller. Its getting the following crash report only in iOS 6 but not getting in iOS 7.

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation', reason: 'preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation must return a supported interface orientation!'
```

I am getting this crash only when presenting the `UIImagePickerController`.

My app supports Portrait orientation so i am using the following code

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate {

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {

    if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(toInterfaceOrientation))
        return YES;

    return NO;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown;
}

- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window {

    return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown);
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {

    return self.interfaceOrientation;
}
```

But only one page will support both portrait and landscape orientation so i enabled all orientations in info.plist

[image]

can any one pls help me that how to fix this crash.

Comment: remove all the methods and through project settings you can ....

Comment: check this twohttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/12690963/preferredinterfaceorientationforpresentation-must-return-a-supported-interface-o

Comment: check this also http://www.scott-sherwood.com/tutorial/ios-6-uiapplicationinvalidinterfaceorientation-exception/

Comment: sorry guys it doesnt helps any more. still crash occurs in iOS6.can you pls help me to fix this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check this [Stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12522491/crash-on-presenting-uiimagepickercontroller-under-ios-6-0/12570501#12570501) This may help you. i had same same issue in a previous project and this helped out me. try it

Comment: sorry it doesnt helps any more. still crash occurs in iOS6.can you pls help me to fix this

Comment: sorry i made mistake while creating category.its working fine. thanks