# UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation must return a supported interface orientation

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation', reason: 'preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation must return a supported interface orientation!'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110849c65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001104e2bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110849b9d +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
3   UIKit                               0x0000000110d8713c -[UIViewController _preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentationInWindow:fromInterfaceOrientation:] + 487
4   UIKit                               0x00000001112ffa6b -[_UIFullscreenPresentationController _adjustOrientationIfNecessaryInWindow:forViewController:preservingViewController:] + 330
5   UIKit                               0x0000000110d4ed37 -[UIPresentationController _presentWithAnimationController:interactionController:target:didEndSelector:] + 707
6   UIKit                               0x0000000110d7e576 -[UIViewController _presentViewController:modalSourceViewController:presentationController:animationController:interactionController:completion:] + 756
7   UIKit                               0x0000000110d7f76e -[UIViewController _presentViewController:withAnimationController:completion:] + 3079
8   UIKit                               0x0000000110d816c1 __62-[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:]_block_invoke + 132
9   UIKit                               0x0000000110d815e5 -[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:] + 229
10  redminete                           0x000000010ff92a11 -[LoginViewController btnsingin:] + 1537
11  UIKit                               0x0000000110c43d62 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 75
12  UIKit                               0x0000000110d5550a -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 467
13  UIKit                               0x0000000110d548d9 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 522
14  UIKit                               0x0000000110c90958 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 735
15  UIKit                               0x0000000110c91282 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 682
16  UIKit                               0x0000000110c57541 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 246
17  UIKit                               0x0000000110c64cdc _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent + 18265
18  UIKit                               0x0000000110c3f59c _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 2066
19  CoreFoundation                      0x000000011077d431 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
20  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001107732fd __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 269
21  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110772934 __CFRunLoopRun + 868
22  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110772366 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
23  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000113d6fa3e GSEventRunModal + 161
24  UIKit                               0x0000000110c428c0 UIApplicationMain + 1282
25  redminete                           0x000000010ff9bd93 main + 99
26  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000112ded145 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Below is my Sample code

```
- (IBAction)btnsingin:(id)sender {
     NSString * storyboardName=@"Main";
            UIStoryboard *storyboard =[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle:nil];
            UITabBarController *tabBar =[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainTabBar"];
            [self presentViewController:tabBar animated:YES completion:Nil];

}
```

How to solve this issue.

Comment: Did you try to see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12690963/preferredinterfaceorientationforpresentation-must-return-a-supported-interface-o?rq=1 ?

Comment: I have user this below code. but not working-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}

Comment: try this -(BOOL)shouldAutorotate { return YES;}

Comment: it's not working return YES.

Comment: error occur line [self presentViewController:tabBar animated:YES completion:Nil];

Comment: Also check what interface orientation is selected in project settings. May be it's incorrect.